# EditorTemplate for a productcategory (foreign key property)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Hello I am trying to create an editortemplate for a productcategory.

The productcategorie class is:

```
public class ProductCategorie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Gewicht { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
}
```

The Product class is:

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        ...
        public ProductCategorie Categorie { get; set; }    
    }
```

Now in the edit view that I auto created(scaffolding) I got:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Categorie, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Categorie)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Categorie)
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see I use the editorFor so I can then use a EditorTemplate for it!

But it crashes since it somehow doesn t give it a model.(it gives a NullReferenceException on the Model, the model is null, but I need it so I can know what SelectListItem has to have True at Selected!)

Here is the probleming ProductCategorie.cshtml file that is in the EditorTemplates

```
@using Foo.Data
@using Foo.Models
@model ProductCategorie
@{
    var items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    using (var context = new FooDbContext())
    {
        List<ProductCategorie> categorielijst = context.ProductCategorieen.ToList();
        categorielijst.ForEach(x => items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Naam, Value = x.Id.ToString(), Selected = x.Id == ((ProductCategorie)Model).Id }));
    }
}
@Html.DropDownList("", items)
```

So basicly I am asking how can I get the Model or the data of the current selected item when editing an item that has a property that is actualy a foreign key item.

If you got any questions feel free to ask.

(I use EF 6 code first, ASP.Net MVC 5)

Comment: You don't have a `@model` directive in the editor template. Can you confirm this exists?

Comment: yes even with that I still get a NullException on the model

Comment: Can you update your code in your question to reflect that you've added that directive.. just so we can be sure its in there properly?

Comment: Done sorry, I cutted some code to shorten it but forgot this important piece :)

Comment: So, just to clarify: `Model` in the EditorTemplate is null at this line: `((ProductCategorie)Model).Id`.. correct? BTW: You really shouldn't be instantiating a new `DbContext` in your view.. :/

Comment: Yes, but also when I put a breakpoint at var items = new List<SelectListItem>(); (the first line in there) and look at the Model variable, it is also null :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42444/discussion-between-maximc-and-simon-whitehead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this in SO chat.

Basically, the `Model.Categorie` property was `null`.. hence why the EditorTemplate had `null` passed into it.

Glad to help :)